# Prototype object when looping through array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, prototype

I'm getting confusing results when looping through an array.

Filling the array looks like

```
var tables = [];
// ...
// t is table as jQuery object
tables[t.attr('id')] = t;
```

Later, when looping through the tables array, I'm getting one more element than I've actually added. The program breakes when the other object reaches t.removeClass()

```
for (t in tables) {
    var t = tables[t];
    t.removeClass(...);
}
```

Visual Studio Debugger describes the other object as "clone", which is the first method of the prototype object/property(?).

```
tables
    [prototype]
        [Methods]
            clone
            ...
        [prototype]
    MyTable0
    MyTable1
```

I've read that every javascript object comes with a prototype property but why is prototype here treated as an object?

Comment: Can you show the code that populates the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration for tables should be:

```
var tables = {};
```

Comment: It looks like OP should use an object as map instead of an array, indeed. If you explain it a little, you'll have my +1.

Comment: Because what you want to do is associate t.attr('id') to your t object. Arrays do not behave like that.

Answer (score 1):

Note : if your id aren't numbers, then you don't need an array, look at the other answer.

To loop over an array, don't use the `for..in` construct.

Use

```
for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
    var t = tables[i];
    t.removeClass(...);
}
```

or if you don't care for IE8 :

```
tables.forEach(function(t) {
    t.removeClass(...);
});
```

or with jQuery :

```
$.each(tables, function(_,t){
    t.removeClass(...);
});
```

Side note : it looks like somebody poorly enriched the prototype of the native Array class. It's [generally seen as bad practice](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). Doing so *and* making the property enumerable is even worse. You should consider dropping or fixing the library you use.

Comment: tables.length is 0 since it's an associative array. tables.forEach doesn't work either.

Comment: @user2558051 then you shouldn't use an array at all. See eggward's answer.